# SMTP ERROR on phpmailer with right credentials

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I have done all changes turned off two-step verification and also turned on less secure app. But when I see PHP mailer to send an email it prints me this error. 
The same code was working fine in localhost but when i uploaded it on server it used to call this error. I am using AWS server
 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed:
How can i bypass this to use my contact form of website

```
    <?php
get_header(); ?>
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    require 'wp-content/themes/oceanwp/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
    require 'wp-content/themes/oceanwp/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'wp-content/themes/oceanwp/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

    // require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = '*****@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '******';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($_POST['email_of_user'], $_POST['name_of_user']);
        $mail->addAddress('&&&&@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('&&&&@gmail.com', 'VASTRA');               // Name is optional

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject_of_user'] ;
        $mail->Body    = '<p style="text-align:center">'.$_POST['message_of_user'].'</p>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'I have a qquery';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
} //end if loop


?>
```

Comment: can you show code?

Comment: Edited the answer above

Comment: First of all set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what the server is saying. Next read the troubleshooting guide, especially [the parts about gmail authentication](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps). Third, search before you post - this question has been answered literally hundreds of times before. You say you're using AWS SMTP, but you're clearly not - you have gmail's mail server address in your `Host` property.

Comment: You're also forging the from address: look at [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) for how to do this correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use this example:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//From email address and name
$mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com"); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply");

//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

This example use simple domain email and sent it without set password or any smtp parameter

Comment: This doesn't address the problem at all as it's not using SMTP.

Comment: I gave a reason for downvoting – your answer has nothing to do with the question asked. Also you can't send from a gmail address (what was asked) when relaying via localhost because it's forgery.